# div near cursor onclick jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to show a div near the cursor when you click on a span with the id as equipment in jquery and css

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a hidden div:

```
<div id="message">
This is a message
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#message { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

and then show it:

```
$("#equipment").click(function(evt) {
  $("#message").css({
    top: evt.pageY,
    left: evt.pageX
  }).toggle();
});
```

Here's a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#equipment").click(function(evt) {
    $("#message").css({
      top: evt.pageY + 5,
      left: evt.pageX + 5
    }).show();
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body, div { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 none; }
#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 600px; }
#equipment { color: green; }
#message { display: none; position: absolute; text-align: center; padding: 10px; width: 120px; background: red; color: white; font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor <span id="equipment">incididunt ut labore et dolore</span> magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div id="message">This is a message</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well that's a 100% working example there. What exactly does "nothing is happening" mean?

Comment: all works greate. adding some css and some animates can get good result

Answer (score 2):

Until you give us more specific information, here's your solution:

```
$("span#equipment").click(function(){
  $(".invisiDiv").show(); // .toggle() if you need it to close with next click
});
```

--

```
<p><span id="equipment">Equipment</span></p>
<div class="invisiDiv" style="display:none;">
  <p>This div will be shown once you click on the span element above</p>
</div>
```

If you need this `.invisiDiv` to say near your mouse at all times, you can dynamically reposition it according to [the current x/y position of the mouse](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position):

```
$("span#equipment").click(function(e){
  $(".invisiDiv")
    .css({top:e.pageX,left:e.pageY})
    .show(); // .toggle() if you need it to close with next click
});
```

And add the following CSS rules to it:

```
.invisiDiv { position:absolute; width:100px; height:15px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

another way could be like this

HTML:

```
<span>click!</span>
```

Jquery:

```
$('span').click(function()
{
  $(this).showDiv('<div>I AM DIV</div>');
});

//plugin
jQuery.fn.showDiv = function (html) 
{
    var pos = $(this).position();
    $(html).insertAfter('span').css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: (pos.top + 20) + "px",//customize top position
        left: (pos.left) + "px"//customize left position
    }).fadeIn();
    return this;
}
```

Some CSS:

```
div{
    background:red;
    display:none;height:50px;width:50px
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:50px;
    background:green;
}
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/a5Zxk/1/