# how do I display a div after ajax call success next to mouse position

Tags: jquery

The question that I am posting here is somewhat similar to question posted [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967531/div-near-cursor-onclick-jquey)  but I am trying to set the properties upon the completion of ajax request.

The page displays all the feedbacks in 'ul li', each feedback has two voting elements 'voteup' and 'votedown'

Now when the user clicks voteup element the vote is recorded using jquery's ajax (i.e. vote function below)

The response text is populated in the 'divProcessing' div.

on the click of element voteup or votedown, I call the vote function as

```
vote('{$feedback.id},'voteup');
```

here is the code that I have written

```
function vote(action,feedbackId)
            {
                var $divEmail = $('#divProcessing');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'index.php?client='+$.getUrlVar('client')+'&page=ajax',
                    data: {option: 'vote', action: action, feedbackId: feedbackId},
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data,evt)
                    {
                        $divEmail.html(data)
                        .css({top:evt.pageY, left:evt.pageX})
                        .show();
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(){$divEmail.addClass('show_loading_in_center')},
                    complete: function(){$divEmail.removeClass('show_loading_in_center')}
                });
            }
```

Everything is working fine here but I need to show this 'divProcessing' near to the voting element being clicked (or near mouse position).

please help me show the divprocessing next to the img tag that is being clicked.

I hope I am able to explain my question clearly.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to set the CSS `position` of the element to `fixed`. This will position the element relative to the screen, no matter where the element is defined and how scrolled the page is. This would be done by switching from:

```
.css({top:evt.pageY, left:evt.pageX})
```

To:

```
.css({position:'fixed', top:evt.screenY, left:evt.screenX})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Max S :),
I did that already, but it is not that nice as showing the response next to the voting element., isn't it.?

Comment: Well, if the voting element is clicked, then the mouse position will be exactly where the click was, i.e. on/near the image. However, I just noticed that you used pageX/pageY, while for fixed screenX/screenY would make more sense; edited.

Comment: I cannot use the click event to determine the position because to determine the click I have to create a separate ID attribute for every img element generated. :(

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case. Since you are capturing a click event on the vote, all you need are that event's attributes. The images are never touched this way.

Comment: :) :) :) :)
thanks man your comment gave me an idea.
I simply used the find method of jquery to find for every vote element being clicked and displayed the div next to every matched element
thanks a lot.